# ASP.NET Core blazor dependency injection error: System.NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, orm, blazor

Using SqlSugar ORM, based on blazor, dependency injection business service, an error is reported when calling, and it is empty。
SqlSugarService：

```
public static class SqlSugarService
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SqlSugarService));
    public static void AddSqlSugarSevice(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (services == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    
        services.AddScoped<ISqlSugarClient>(o =>
        {
            var listConfig = new List<ConnectionConfig>();
            listConfig.Add(new ConnectionConfig
            {
                DbType = DbType.SqlServer,
                ConnectionString = "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;DataBase=Test;Uid=sa;Pwd=123456",
                IsAutoCloseConnection = true,
                InitKeyType = InitKeyType.Attribute
            });
            var dbContext = new SqlSugarClient(listConfig);
            
            return dbContext;
        });
    }
}
```

The interface：

```
public interface IReportRepository
{
     public DataTable GetTest(string sql);
}
```

Interface implementation：

```
public class ReportRepository : IReportRepository
{
    private ISqlSugarClient _dbBase;
    public ReportRepository(ISqlSugarClient sqlSugar)
    {
        _dbBase = sqlSugar;
    }

    public DataTable GetTest(string sql)
    {
        return _dbBase.Ado.GetDataTable(sql);
    }
}
```

Injection：

```
services.AddSqlSugarSevice();
services.TryAddTransient<IReportRepository, ReportRepository>();
```

Used in component code：

```
public partial class Report
{
    [Inject]
    public IReportRepository ReportService { get; set; }

    public Report()
    {
        ReportService.GetTest("select * from test");
    }
}
```

**ERROR :**

> ```
> System.NullReferenceException,HResult=0x80004003,Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object, Source=MyReport
> ```

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: `_dbBase = sqlSugar as SqlSugarClient;` Why are you doing that `as`?

Comment: After modifying the code, the same error is reported：```
        private ISqlSugarClient _dbBase;
        public ReportRepository(ISqlSugarClient sqlSugar)
        {
            _dbBase = sqlSugar;
        }```

Comment: Think of it logically - the dependency has to be injected _after_ the `Report` constructor has fired. But you are using the dependency _in the constructor_. Logically, that isn't possible. How would the DI container have managed to inject it in there _before_ the constructor is finished? If you really want to use it in the constructor you need to use constructor injection, not `[Inject]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just tested it. After [Inject] was injected, the button event was successful. However, when using constructor injection, a new error occurred, and I don't know why. I have added a screenshot of the new error in the question

Comment: That is alas a new question. Can you write that up separately to here?